# python call remote object method asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, zeromq, rpc, python-multiprocessing

I have a class like following.

```
class R(object):
    def __init__(self, initial=0, incr=2):
        self.initial = initial
        self.incr = incr
        self.value = initial

    def add(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.value += self.incr

    def mul(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.value *= self.incr

    def get(self):
        return self.value
```

I want to create a *server* that will do the following.

- for each init request it creates an object **`R`** in a different process
- for each call to `.add()`, `.mul()` methods, the *server* calls that process and applies corresponding calls. But it is time consuming, so it returns immediately. On the other hand the remote `R` process is still executing the `.add()` or `.mul()` methods' bodies.
- If the server receives a call to the `.get()` method, it calls the corresponding process and applies `.get()` to it. But this time it waits for the result and when the result is there, it terminates the remote `R` object.

**How this can be achieved?**

*What I have tried so far?*
I created R object using `multiprocessing.Process`. Then send commands to it using `multiprocessing.Queue` with `put_nowait`.

But it seems I have to do control the flow myself. Is there any other framework, tool that does the same thing?

The server is written in `zmq`, But I am open to change it to a different solution.

Comment: Perfectly doable in ZeroMQ. Why to waste CPU / overheads by using inappropriate tools? ZeroMQ allows you to adaptively spin-up remote worker-instances and load-balance / fail-safe-heal their actual performance and also their (un-)-avoidable silent exits. The logic is in your hands, the performance need not be cannibalised by any language- or environment-driven priors. Yes, you have to do the flow control, but this is your strength to do so, not a weakness - isn't it? If your needs are to gain more performance, may go this way, using ZeroMQ or even a more lightweight & fat-free nanomsg tools.

Comment: @user3666197 I did it with ZeroMQ! Your comment inspired me a lot. if you write it as an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped, Sir, inspire any further bright moves. Good Luck in that & stay tuned :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly doable in ZeroMQ.

---

### Why to waste CPU / overheads by using inappropriate tools?

ZeroMQ allows you to adaptively spin-up remote worker-instances and load-balance / fail-safe-heal their actual performance and also their (un-)-avoidable silent exits.

The logic is in your hands, the **performance need not be cannibalised** by any language- or environment-driven priors.

Yes, you have to do the flow control, but this is your strength to do so, not a weakness - isn't it?

If your needs are to **gain more performance**, may go this way, using ZeroMQ / **[pyzmq](/questions/tagged/pyzmq)** or even a more lightweight & fat-free **[nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg)** tools. <sub>– user3666197 Nov 2 '17 at 17:08</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) frameworks are built to satisfy your needs.

They are designed to allow distributed computations across multiple nodes abstracting the control flow.

What you typically end up doing is focusing on the execution logic and setting up the workers. The frameworks should take care of the rest.

Celery supports multiple queuing backends, but I'm not sure ZeroMQ is among them.

Comment: Are you sure celery can handle stateful tasks? Here my task is stateful. If you call add(), mul() and get() it should return the end result.

Comment: I guess you can easily track the state in global variables or applying the `@app.task` decorator to a class method and store the results in its attributes. For more sophisticated cases I'd use a backend such as Redis or Memcached to store persistent data. You can read more about states and results in the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#states).

Comment: With all due respect, **storing persistent data into** *(cit.:) "**backend such as Redis or Memcached*" is a very expensive step** if speaking about a high-performance motivated distributed-computing that the O/P is clear and obvious to go into.

Comment: Not so clear and obvious I'd say as the OP claims the `add` and `mul` operations are "time consuming". To me sounds the OP is rather looking for abstracting the management of the task flow: "it seems I have to do control the flow myself. Is there any other framework, tool that does the same thing?".